# Request to undelete a quite valuable thread on SO

Tags: support, status-declined, deleted-questions, undelete

Can we please undelete this post [What happened to the Substance LaF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898028/what-happened-to-the-substance-laf) (10k+), that was deleted by Will on April 9 at 21:19?

I feel it should be un-deleted because:

- It is a very interesting thread
- It isn't outdated, with a long history
- It has actual links to a very nice theme (Look and Feel) for Java Swing

Comment: You should add reasons/arguments to why it should be undeleted

Comment: Seems pretty much too localized? What is the value of undeleting that one?

Comment: @Bart - since when are too localized questions **deleted**?

Comment: @AdamRackis I'm not saying it should have been deleted. I'm asking what the value is of undeleting that one. That said, for now at least, a version of that post seems to be available here, if you're looking to salvage content: http://efreedom.com/Question/1-5898028/Happened-Substance-LaF?showall=true#additionalAnswersMarker

Comment: @Bart - ok, fair enough.  I don't know anything about what that post is about, but it seemed to have attracted a lot of upvotes, and it doesn't seem like the sort of garbage we should be deleting; having that post exist doesn't seem to make the internet a worse place.

Comment: There are lots of interesting topics, but not all are appropriate for SO. *What happened to XXX?* doesn't seem on topic for SO, even if XXX is a useful tool.

Comment: @AdamRackis - the Great Typo Cleanup went through and deleted a bunch of typo questions, since they were the very definition of "too localized".  Not saying that's the case here, but just answering your question.

Comment: @BlahBlah - I'm sorry to hear that.  Shog's stated criteria for when a post should be deleted—sorry, don't recall when exactly he said it—is that the post makes the internet a worse place.  I can't see how a typo question meets that standard.

Comment: Also, we're talking about a question that's two years old. So the question is really *What happened to XXX two years ago?*

Comment: yes its two year old but with care about contnets and all edits aren't outdated

Comment: @AdamRackis Why wouldn't too localized questions be deleted? The whole point of too localized is it's (assumedly) not going to be of use to any other visitors, so there's no reason to keep them around.

Comment: @Anthony - a raft of Java typo questions clutter search results, and make it difficult to find useful content; you could say their existence harms SO for that reason.  That argument cannot be made in this case.  This question does not *hurt the site*, and does not *make the internet a worse place*.

Comment: @Bart from the perspective of a backend developer everything on the desktop seems to be evaluated as too localized ;-)

Comment: disagree heartily with the decision to delete the question - it's a question about a valued tool in the Swing community with a history so twisted that it is hard to find. For the last two years the question had been a central point for lookup its whereabouts and status. That _should be_ appropriate for SO.

Comment: Something I did not know until I tried: "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted."

Comment: @kleopatra - this is becoming a growing problem.  A small cadre of delete enthusiasts (or in this case a single moderator) are seeing to it that off-topic questions like this are not only closed, but **deleted** so nobody with < 10K rep can even *see them*.

Comment: @AdamRackis: [_Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quis_custodiet_ipsos_custodes%3F) I'm confident that the moderators also moderate one another, and I'll accept the result. In the meantime, I've proposed an [alternative](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177105/163188) below. I'd welcome guidance on the idea.

Comment: @trashgod - it's a good thought.  The thing about Tag Wikis is that nobody ever sees them, and everyone hates them.  There have been myriad posts on meta about how to make them better, but nobody has ever really come up with a good idea.  But it's better than nothing, I suppose.

Comment: I've updated the wiki with content from the answers.  I removed that question (which at first glance was "why is this website offline?") while cleaning up the [tag:online-resources] tag.  I see now that there's a bit more to it than that, but it's still in the class of questions requesting links or products.  :/ I don't particularly see a reason to undelete, but if any other mod wants to reopen I won't have a food baby about it.

Comment: @Won't thank you for edits, rest of your comments we can leaving without any additional requests nor flamewars, your possition here, your job, (my view) I'm voting to delete to another type of questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several [respected contributors](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/topusers) to the Java Swing tag have expressed a desire to retain this [valuable resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5898028/230513), but "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted." An alternative might be to migrate the essential details to the relevant [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/substance/info), subject of course to reverting or [burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20%5Bfaq%5D%20burnination).

Comment: good idea, required un_delete before,

Comment: I defer to your and @kleopatra's greater experience in this area, but I'll stop by the tag for a copyedit.

Answer (score 7):

StackOverflow need not be a link-farmy-type site to redirect people to a project's page. While I have seen questions like this on StackOverflow escape the ire of the diamond mods, it doesn't make it right for them to exist. The creators of that project have the onus to maintain their site pages and own redirects.

Comment: +1 for like as a quote from FAQ, but SO is as community is, simple I disagre with delete, this post (since is localized) should be closed only, be sure I'm most active on SO ....

Comment: -1 that question has nothing to do with link farming

Comment: @kleopatra I'm disagree with this citation too, but meta has own rulles as you know very well :-), see another one

Comment: @kleopatra: The question and associated answers were looking for new links to an old project.